# Show that in a group of four people it is more likely than not that two of them were born on the same day of the week.

Tags: probability, birthday

I've started the working :

Possible combinations : AB AC AD BC BD CD = 6

P(2 people born same day of week) = 1 - P(No people born on same day of week)

=1−((7/7)⋅(6/7)⋅(5/7)⋅(4/7))=1−(120/343)=223/343≈0.65

I'm not sure if this is correct and would really appreciate any working or answers.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.  You're asking, "What is the probability that the probability ...?"

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean, "In a group of four people, what is the probability that two of them were born on the same day of the week"? Or perhaps, "How many people do we need such that it is more likely than not that two of them were born on the same day of the week"?

Comment: What does the question **really** ask? (_Not_ in your own words...)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Did you mean to write $1 - \frac{7}{7} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{7}$?  You have an extra factor of $7^4$ in your denominator for the excluded cases.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this website.

Comment: I've rephrased, can you help now? @DavidC.Ullrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As N. F. Taussig commented, you have too many $7$s and should have

$$= 1 - \left({\frac{7}{7} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{7}}\right) = 1 - \frac{120}{343} = \frac{223}{343} \approx 0.65%%$$

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP got?

Comment: @SomeGuy The OP has $1 - \left(\dfrac{\frac{7}{7} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{7}}{7^4}\right)$ which has an extra $7^4$ in the denominator